# Get-ADUser fails when using a wildcard and variable in the same search string

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have a command to search for a user by their proxy email address.

```
Get-ADUser -Filter {ProxyAddresses -like "*bob@bob.com*"}
```

This command returns the record for the user I want and it works just fine.

I can also create a variable to store the exact string that will be found and search for that and I also get the correct result.

```
$email = "smtp:bob@bob.com"
Get-ADUser -Filter {ProxyAddresses -like $email}
```

I don't want to do the above in the off chance that the record I am searching for is not smtp: (some may be sip or others).

However, I am iterating through a list of users so I need to look for $email instead of the actual string. I want to do this:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter {ProxyAddresses -like "*$email*"}
```

This returns $null. I can't figure out why. I've opened a new window and set $email equal to an address that I know works when I type it by itself, but the result is still $null.

I assume this has to do with adding the wildcards, but I can't figure out what the problem is.

Perhaps it is the quotation marks, since the following also fails:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter {ProxyAddresses -like "$email"}
```

I have always been able to use variables in strings before, so I don't understand why it fails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My usual recommendation is to use `-LDAPFilter` rather than `-Filter`.

```
Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(proxyAddresses=*$email*)"
```

Internally, Get-ADUser must translate the `-Filter` to an LDAP filter anyway, and as you have seen, getting `-Filter` to work with embedded variables can be tricky.

Comment: This has resolved the problem, thank you. I didn't know there was another filter type to use, and it has the upside of being slightly faster! (though searching proxyaddresses instead of mail is tending to be incredibly slow, but we've set some people up with aliased addresses so it has to be this way)

Answer (score 0):

I think it wont work, because you use $email inside of `{}`.

Inside the function term, you can't use variables from outside.
You have to put it into the global scope or access it with having.

So try this one:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter {ProxyAddresses -like "*$having:email*"}
```

or set $email to global:

```
$global:email = $email
Get-ADUser -Filter {ProxyAddresses -like "*$global:email*"}
```

Just have a look at the [Scopes](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847849.aspx)

Comment: I am able to reference $email just fine. I have tried setting $email to the exact address (smtp:bob@bob.com) and it works. "$email" however does not work, so maybe it has to do with the quotes, but I can't see how that would matter.

Comment: it does not work, because the variable you use `$email` cannot be accessed in your filter. in your Filter, you use a script block `//start of script block --> {  ....Filter.....  } <-- End of Scriptblock.` And in this scriptblock, you cannot acces to $email, because it is in another scope. You have to access $email while using the scope $having or putting $email into the global scope.    `